# How to scroll my UIViewController content?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, xcode7.2

I've been trying to search for a swift version of a solution to no avail. I was wondering how I can make my view controller scroll content. Right now it's just static, and there's more content below, which I'm unable to scroll.

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    let postsId = "postsId"
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    view.addSubview(profileContainerView)
    view.addSubview(profileTabCollection)
    view.addSubview(containerForCollectionView)
    view.addSubview(scrollView)

    scrollView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(view.frame.size.width).active = true
    scrollView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(view.frame.size.height).active = true
    scrollView.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.centerXAnchor).active = true
    scrollView.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.centerYAnchor).active = true

    scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
    scrollView.delegate = self


    containerForCollectionView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(scrollView.frame.size.width).active = true
    containerForCollectionView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(scrollView.frame.size.height).active = true
    containerForCollectionView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(profileTabCollection.bottomAnchor).active = true

    profileContainerView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(scrollView.frame.size.width).active = true
    profileContainerView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(250).active = true
    profileContainerView.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(scrollView.centerXAnchor).active = true
    profileContainerView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).active = true

    profileTabCollection.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(profileContainerView.widthAnchor).active = true
    profileTabCollection.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(50).active = true
    profileTabCollection.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.centerXAnchor).active = true
    profileTabCollection.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(profileContainerView.bottomAnchor).active = true

}

lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
    let sv = UIScrollView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,1024,768))
    sv.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height * 3)
    sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return sv
}()


let containerForCollectionView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()
```

Comment: cal this `scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height + 500)` after `scrollView.heightAnchor`

Comment: Hm, it doesn't seem to scroll

Comment: are you using storyboard? it seems some problem with constrains.

Comment: try setting the contentsize in the viewwillappear

Comment: Add screenshot of storyboard ,constraint . Then only we will be understand the exact problem . Whatever you will ask it should be complete.

Comment: Hi @ManiaChamp, I did all of this programmatically out of preference. I did updated my code to give a better view of my constraints.

Comment: @SaintThread, would it better suit me to use layoutSubviews instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous reasons why this won't work. Since you don't provide enough information to be sure what it is, i'd recommend reading this (especially Duncan C's answer) carefully.

[how do i alter the position of a UIImage inside a imageView in SWIFT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30002204/5259993)

Answer (score 0):

Write these lines in override `layoutSubviews()` method.

```
scrollView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.widthAnchor).active = true
scrollView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.heightAnchor).active = true
```

Make sure you created UIScrollView in your UIViewController, otherwise it won't work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using swift 2.0  and you have used "UIScrollViewDelegate"- you need to add this method

```
   func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imgview
    }
```

And if you are using swift 3.0 - you need this function

```
func viewForZooming( in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imgview
    }
```